# Using 3rd Party SMTP Host for PHP app via shared hosting?

Tags: php, smtp

I have a situation where I'm trying to host an PHP/MySQL based custom app on IIS via a shared hosting account. The hosting company is discountasp.net and it appears that in that environment I don't have access to the php.ini file where I'd normally set up the authentication/credentials for outbound SMTP...

Can anyone recommend an approach on this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ini_set?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), which is a pretty good library to send emails with PHP and allows to send through any SMTP server.